# Paypal Error: This account is not approved for the authorization service

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout

I have a web app to sell music. The artists put their mp3s and their paypal accounts and then the users can buy the songs.

I'm using the PHP Api for Paypal and the Express Checkout. Some users can sell their music with no problems, but other have this error:

```
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-09-22T09:16:15Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 1549c264a8645
[ACK] => Failure
[VERSION] => 115
[BUILD] => 12932421
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 11623
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => This account is not approved for the authorization service.
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => This account is not approved for the authorization service. To enable this service, contact PayPal customer service
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

This is the response when everything is ok:

```
[TOKEN] => EC-3MD61457NF0416501
[TIMESTAMP] => 2014-09-22T09:46:53Z
[CORRELATIONID] => 6c8d20db85b
[ACK] => Success
[VERSION] => 115
[BUILD] => 12932421
```

What's the problem? Maybe they don't have a paypal account for selling or receiving money? (personal account)

If that is the problem, how I can check the account type with the email?

Comment: can you post the complete response from the PayPal here including the correlation id ?

Comment: I have added the complete response.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using PayPal Express Checkout Parallel Payments . One of the the seller email address in the request that you are passing to the PayPal is unconfirmed due to which you are getting this error. I will advise you to get the email address of the receiver for the failed request and request them to confirm their PayPal email address .

Once its done you should get rid of this error .

Comment: The API don't lets you to check if a PayPal address have been validated? However, I have checked the paypal accounts with this utility: https://www.paypal.com/verified/pal= and the two accounts have been validated.

Comment: The utility tells the account is verified but not about the email address . In this case the account is verified but they just need to confirm their email address . Verified and confirmed are two different things . Verification refer to the funding source attached to the account but confirmed refers to the email attached to the PayPal account . Sometimes users forget to click on the link received from the PayPal on the account creation and their account email remains unconfirmed .